# Group of text field in Dijit

Tags: javascript, validation, field, dojo

I am having a scenario. In one of the form there are 18 fields in the group of 3, but only one group(3 fields) can have value at a time. 
Can any please tell me how can i do this in the best way, is there any thing like creating group of fields in dijit? 
I can do this via javascript but that script is very ugly please tell me if there is some standard way to do this or some best approach.

There is a dropdown on the form, on the basis of dropdown value fields will be enabled / disabled. But for one value in the dropdown all the fields(group of fields) should be enabled and let users to decided which group of fields he wants to enter. But user can enter one group of fields(which he can choose). So disabling the field is not an option & checking the same via javascript function doesn't look gud.
Hope this clerified more.
Thanks

Comment: What logic determines which group of inputs are active at a time?  Please post some sample markup showing how your form is set up.

Answer (score 0):

I think a nice approach would be to have a controller widget, creating "group" widgets.
On the group widget you would have a onFocus function, a resetFields function.
in each group you would connect on the fields onFocus, and call the callback group function "onFocus". Then the controlelr widget would call all other group widget and do a resetFields.
The group widget resetField function would clear values of the group's fields.

Something like that sounds clean enough ?